# Generic constraint to enforce interface

Tags: c#

Assume I have a class

```
public class A<T>: where T: ISomeInterface
{}
```

Is there anyway to constrain the generic argument to not accept any type of type implementing ISomeInterface? **Note I'm looking for a compile-time solution. I am not interested in runtime solutions.**

I want to disallow

```
B: ISomeInterface
{}

new A<B>();
```

But allow, and indeed require:

```
new A<ISomeInterface>();
```

Comment: This makes no sense. If you can only pass exactly 1 thing as the generic parameter what's the point? You have an [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info) - try explaining what you're trying to to rather than how think it should be achieved

Comment: @Jamiec
The problem is clearly stated. It's not an XY. I'm looking for a solution to achieve a compiletime check that the supplied generic T (to A) is an interface at compile time.

Comment: @gwow12345 this is absolutely, 100% an XY Problem!

Comment: @gwow12345 why do you allow only interfaces?

Comment: @Jamiec The reason it's not an XY problem is because it is a solution of the form I described or no solution at all. The solution is constrained by external factors I have no control over.

Comment: Because `B` _is-a_ `ISomeInterface`, it can be used anywhere that a `ISomeInterface` is required; that's how polymorphism works, generic or otherwise.

Comment: If you have problem with reflection checks, than rewrite them from `someType == typeof(ISomeInterface)` to `typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(someType)`. I can't  imagine any other cases when this may be a problem

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay provably false.
It may implement an interface, but 
typeof(B).IsInterface is false, for example. There are ways to discern interfaces from the types that implements them.

Comment: You basically just defined the XY Problem. "I have constraint X, therefore I think the solution is Y - how do I do Y?". Try telling us more about constraint X and you'll find the solution is probably not Y.

Comment: @Jamiec the constraints are that I may perform no runtime checks and the supplied generic parameter must be an interface. Not implement an interface. I have no access to the usage of the class.

Comment: You'll have to look into static code analysis if you want to enforce that the generic argument is that interface.

Comment: Can you show the code of which you think `T` needs to be exactly `ISomeInterface` for that code to work? I still don't see any reason why you would need this solution.

Comment: @RenéVogt
Simplified example:

`A(string someString, int someInt): this(someString, someInt, new DefaultObjectOfSomeType<T>())`

I have no control over DefaultObjectOfSomeType<T> and it requires T to be an interface. It will throw at runtime if T is an implementation of whatever interface.

I am not allowed to refactor. I am strictly limited to, at compile-time make sure the use does not get a runtime error by suppling an implementation of an interface in an object I have no control over, in a construction chain I am not allowed to change.

Comment: Could you just use `public class A<ISomeInterface>`? That way, no impementations of `ISomeInterface` could be used in the declaration. But that also excludes sub interfaces.

Comment: I'd love to see the code for `DefaultObjectOfSomeType` that throws in such a situation. it shouldn't be possible unless it is doing some silly reflection. Can you decompile it if you don't have source code? I wonder if it just needs a `class` constraint

Comment: Why not just `A(string someString, int someInt): this(someString, someInt, new DefaultObjectOfSomeType<ISomeInterface>())` ?

Comment: @Charlieface
It does exactly a
`if(!typeof(T).IsInterface)
{
throw ...
}`

Comment: @Scroog1
The supplied interface must be centralized. I gave a snippet. In reality there is much, much more code that needs T. It is not desirable to put ISomeInterface everywhere. It is much more desirable to put T everywhere, to make it more flexible. ISomeInterface is not a requirement. What is required i that T is an interface. It can not be hardcoded.

Comment: @FrankPl No. This is a control for external users not to get a runtime error at object construction.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to constrain the generic argument to not accept any type of type implementing ISomeInterface?

No. By its very nature the constraint `where T: ISomeInterface` means anything which implements `ISomeInterface`, or in the case of another interface inherits that interface.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the rest, you can't.

I'm not looking to provide an answer, still the need of **T** to be interface when constructing it can be enforced at runtime (hardcoding), obviously beats the purpose of generic.

```
public interface IB { }

public class B : IB { }

public class A<T> where T : IB
{
    public A()
    {
        // here it's possible to hardcore all your limitations when constructing, if you like only interfaces 
        if (typeof(T).IsClass)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        // or can check what class is not needed if classes implementing interface IB are accepted 
    }
}
```

Where

```
// works
var aib = new A<IB>();

// fails at runtime
var ab = new A<B>();
```

Personally I would limit this is at interface level with generic interfaces used instead of a class. Don't get me wrong, I can see generic classes for a helper or extension class (static) but those should not have any limitations. When having restricted generics instantiation (**new**) an interface will get you out of the trouble of DI, Tests, object casting, arguments passing. Few examples https://dotnetfiddle.net/SPZbBb supporting my point of view.